# Send new password to a new database after password change/reset in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two scripts working together, I need to keep user information synchronized. I have no issues with the username, but for the password, I have tried 2 hooks, 'password_reset' and 'check_passwords', but it is not accomplishing:

```
add_action( 'password_reset', 'change_password_in_other_script', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'check_passwords', 'change_password_in_other_script', 10, 2 );
function change_password_in_other_script( $user, $new_pass ) {

    // OTHER DB CREDENTIALS
    global $addShareDB; 
    // INITIALIZE OTHER DB CONNECTION   
    $mydb = new wpdb( $addShareDB['dbuser'], $addShareDB['dbpass'], $addShareDB['dbname'], $addShareDB['dbhost'] );

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_username = $current_user->user_login;

    $table           = 'enk_account_users';
    $new_password    = md5( $_POST[ 'pwd' ] );
    $query = "UPDATE " . $table . " SET password = '" . $new_password . "' WHERE username = '" . $current_username . "'";
    $mydb->get_results( $query );
}
```

Is there any other hook I can use?

What I am trying to do is ti be able to handle the new created plain text password right after it was inserted into the wordpress database upon password reset or change. So I can update it also into the database of the other framework or maybe even post it to a script in this other framework.

Thank you

Comment: *it is not accomplishing* what? What did you expect once running that code and what's actually happening?

Comment: Prepare your statement with parameters instead of passing raw variables to a query string to avoid sql injections. Additionally, avoid `md5` hashing since it is weak. Use `BCRYPT`, unless it's the framework default pwd hashing method, otherwise you should consider updating it.

Comment: What I am trying to do is ti be able to handle the new created plain text password right after it was inserted into the wordpress database upon password reset or change. So I can update it also into the database of the other framework or maybe even post it to a script in this other framework. And yes, the other framework came already using md5.

Comment: I update it the initial question. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You can use profile_update hook to update the password.

In your theme functions.php file, put profile updates hook.

You can check below code for more reference.

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) 
{
   if ( ! isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) || '' == $_POST['pass1'] ) 
    {
      return;
    }
    elseif(!$_POST['pass1'] === $_POST['pass2']){
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
       //call your API to update password in your framework
    }
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```